# How to run DatabaseUtil.precomputedKNNQuery method of LOF class on two different threads

Tags: elki

I want to reduce runtime of DatabaseUtil.precomputedKNNQuery method by running this method on two different threads and KNNQuery is an interface.

```
    KNNQuery<O> knnq = DatabaseUtil.precomputedKNNQuery(database, relation, getDistanceFunction(), k);
```

I divided this method of LOF class in two parts like this

```
       Callable<KNNQuery> task1(Database database, Relation<O> relation){
        DBIDs idss = relation.getDBIDs();
        ArrayDBIDs aids = (ArrayDBIDs) idss;
        aids = aids.slice(0, (aids.size() / 2));
        aids.size();
        ProxyView<O> pv = new ProxyView<>(aids, relation);
        return () -> {
            return DatabaseUtil.precomputedKNNQuery(database, pv, 
        getDistanceFunction(), k);
        };
    }

    Callable<KNNQuery> task2(Database database, Relation<O> relation) {
        DBIDs idss = relation.getDBIDs();
        ArrayDBIDs aids = (ArrayDBIDs) idss;
        aids = aids.slice(((aids.size() / 2) - 1), aids.size());
        aids.size();
        ProxyView<O> pv2 = new ProxyView<>(aids, relation);
        return () -> {
            return DatabaseUtil.precomputedKNNQuery(database, pv2, getDistanceFunction(), k);
        };
    }
```

Then i invoked both these tasks on two different threads like this in run() method of LOF class

```
 public OutlierResult run(Database database, Relation<O> relation) {
StepProgress stepprog = LOG.isVerbose() ? new StepProgress("LOF", 3) : null;
DBIDs ids = relation.getDBIDs();

 LOG.beginStep(stepprog, 1, "Materializing nearest-neighbor sets.");     
 ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
 List<Callable<KNNQuery>> callables = Arrays.asList(
            task1(database, relation),
            task2(database, relation));
  for (Future<KNNQuery> future : executor.invokeAll(callables)) {
       KNNQuery<O> knnq = future.get();
  // Compute LRDs
  // compute LOF_SCORE of each db object
  // Build result representation
    }
}
```

But i am getting exception which is saying something like this because forEach is providing only output of first future in knnq variable but not the combined output of both future's. Please help me how can i get rid of this exception with example thanks?

```
de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.FileBasedDatabaseConnection.load: 505 ms
LOF #1/3: Materializing nearest-neighbor sets.
de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.index.preprocessed.knn.MaterializeKNNPreprocessor.k: 4
de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.index.preprocessed.knn.MaterializeKNNPreprocessor.k: 4
Materializing k nearest neighbors (k=4): 21751 [100%]  de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.index.preprocessed.knn.MaterializeKNNPreprocessor.precomputation-time: 21470 ms
Materializing k nearest neighbors (k=4): 21750 [100%] 
de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.index.preprocessed.knn.MaterializeKNNPreprocessor.precomputation-time: 22355 ms
LOF #2/3: Computing Local Reachability Densities (LRD).
Task failed
de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.database.datastore.ObjectNotFoundException: Object 
21751 was not found in the database.
at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.database.datastore.memory.ArrayStore.get(ArrayStore.java:69)
at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.index.preprocessed.knn.AbstractMaterializeKNNPreprocessor.get(AbstractMaterializeKNNPreprocessor.java:118)
at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.database.query.knn.PreprocessorKNNQuery.getKNNForDBID(PreprocessorKNNQuery.java:84)
at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.algorithm.outlier.lof.LOF.computeLRD(LOF.java:292)
at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.algorithm.outlier.lof.LOF.computeLRDs(LOF.java:277)
at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.algorithm.outlier.lof.LOF.run(LOF.java:244)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.algorithm.AbstractAlgorithm.run(AbstractAlgorithm.java:89)
at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.workflow.AlgorithmStep.runAlgorithms(AlgorithmStep.java:100)
at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.KDDTask.run(KDDTask.java:109)
at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.application.KDDCLIApplication.run(KDDCLIApplication.java:58)
at [...]
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? You seem to be splitting a data set in two parts, but what for?

Comment: i want to reduce runtime of this method by running this method on two different threads. Now i think i told reason why i am doing this so there is no reason left for down voting my question

Comment: But if you split your data into A and B, won't you be missing results where one point is in A and the other is in B?

Comment: As is, the question will likely not be useful to anybody else but you - it's not clear what you are trying to do, and why. Maybe if you *edit* it to better explain what and why, then maybe it will become useful.

Comment: did you worked with Elki ?

Comment: i edited my question check and remove down vote

Comment: "running his method on two threads" is *not* a good explanation of your *intentions*. What for? "I divided this method...' which method? And avoid screenshots of text...

Comment: i edited please now check and tell me please which screenshots of text you are talking about

Comment: You realize that kNN is based on pairs of points, so if you split the data, you lose neighbors?

Comment: reason of not using screenshots if stackoverflow give us an option? what is the criteria of calculating pairs of points or neighbors ?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/ #2: Look at the definition of all-kNN, and you'll see why you cannot just split your data set in two. You love results.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse thanks for guiding. now check i edited my question is it now ok?

Comment: now i added full stacktrace

Comment: now here is complete stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

If you split your data set this way, one partitions neighbors will not see the other partitions neighbors.

You seem to want to parallelize LOF. Why don't you just use the existing parallel LOF?

https://elki-project.github.io/releases/current/doc/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/algorithm/outlier/lof/parallel/ParallelLOF.html

You can study the source code to see how we parallelize this with a map-reduce like framework:

https://github.com/elki-project/elki/blob/9908f56f14ec76912745369edb68c07c4339eae0/elki-outlier/src/main/java/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/algorithm/outlier/lof/parallel/ParallelLOF.java#L114L133

Alternatively - and closer to what you are doing right now - you can do two partitions, run LOF on both, then "join" the two LOF results by copying. There is no benefit in joining the kNN results before running LOF, as they will remain independent - one object from partition A will not see neighbors from partition B the way you set it up by partitioning the data.

Note that `DatabaseUtil.precomputedKNNQuery` is a convenience method for functionality used in a number of methods. But it's not "required" to be used. The `ParallelLOF` version does not use it, because it is not parallel.

In future ELKI 0.8 I hope we will have infrastructure in place that can automatically set up indexes (including such precomputed) as necessary; and maybe with a flag that allows this to be done in parallel (or not - for runtime comparisons, single-threaded algorithms usually yield more meaningful results).

Comment: Method DatabaseUtil.precomputedKNNQuery is not just only calculating distance between the query instance and all training samples?

Comment: No, it is precomputing *all* kNN. For a single result, one would not precompute, but just use the regular kNN queries. This is for use in methods that require the kNN *repeatedly* (hence, need to store them) for *each* object, such as LOF. The naive approach, without index, needs n² distance computations. You can look at the source code to see what it does!

Comment: you are talking about map-reduce framework of hadoop?

Comment: Yes, that API is a little bit inspired by map-reduce. But map reduce != hadoop.